# HttpPostedFileBase Stream Upload to AWS SDK Bucket has no Data

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filestream, aws-sdk

I'm testing how to upload to AWS using SDK with a sample .txt file from a web app.  The file uploads to the Bucket, but the downloaded file from the bucket is just an empty Notepad document without the text from the original uploaded file.  I'm new to working with streams, so I'm not sure what could be wrong here.  Does anyone see why the data wouldn't be sent in the transfer request?  Thanks in advance!

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest1))
{
    //Save File to Bucket
    using (FileStream txtFileStream = (FileStream)UploadedHttpFileBase.InputStream)
    {
        try
        {
            TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility();
            fileTransferUtility.Upload(txtFileStream, bucketLocation, 
                UploadedHttpFileBase.FileName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Both TransferUtility and PutObjectRequest/PutObjectResponse/AmazonS3Client.PutObject saved a blank text file. Then, after having some trouble instantiating a new FileStream, a MemoryStream used after resetting the starting position to zero still saved a blank text file. Any ideas?

New Code:

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest1))
{
    Stream saveableStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (Stream source = (Stream)UploadedHttpFileBase.InputStream)
    {
        source.Position = 0;
        source.CopyTo(saveableStream);
    }

    //Save File to Bucket                                        
    try
    {
        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketLocation,
            Key = UploadedHttpFileBase.FileName, 
            InputStream = saveableStream
        };
        PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(request);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer had something to do with nesting, which is still a little beyond my understanding, and not because the code posted here was inherently wrong.  This code came after an initial StreamReader which checked the first line of the text file to determine whether or not to save the file.  After moving the code out from the while loop doing the ReadLines, the upload worked.  Everything works as it's supposed to now that the validation is reorganized so that there's no need for the nested Stream or MemoryStream.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably that TransferUtility doesn't work good with temporary upload files. Try to copy your input stream somewhere (e.g. into other not-so-temporary file, or even MemoryStream if you're **sure** it would not give you OutOfMemory at some point). Another thing is to get rid of TransferUtility and use low-level AmazonS3Client.PutObject with which you get finer control over Stream lifetime (do not forget that you'll need to implement some retrying as S3 API is prone to returning random temporary errors).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Andrey.  I used both TransferUtility and PutObjectRequest/PutObjectResponse/AmazonS3Client.PutObject, and both saved a blank text file.  How would one copy the input stream to a non-temporary file without using MemoryStream?

Comment: I've used MemoryStream and reset the starting position to zero just in case, but a blank file is still saved.  Any ideas?